# Android scene transition issue

Tags: android, transition, scene

I am trying to change one scene to another scene using transition framework.

#### `MainActivity.java`

```
mSceneRoot = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root_scene);
        calendarScene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(mSceneRoot, R.layout.content_main_scene1,this);
        searchScene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(mSceneRoot, R.layout.content_main_scene2,this);

searchTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchTextEdit);
        searchTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    TransitionManager.go(searchScene);
                } else
                {
                    TransitionManager.go(calendarScene);
                }
            }
        });
```

#### content_root.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root_scene">
        <include layout="@layout/content_main_scene1"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`content_main_scene2` has additional `listView`. 
Finally I got the exception:

```
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2413)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2373)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6945)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6924)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.rootViewRequestFocus(View.java:4746)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout(ViewGroup.java:4042)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViews(ViewGroup.java:3971)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.transition.Scene.enter(Scene.java:163)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.transition.TransitionManager.changeScene(TransitionManager.java:193)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.transition.TransitionManager.go(TransitionManager.java:342)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.freelance.wwtlf.info.MainActivity$2.onFocusChange(MainActivity.java:71)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:4836)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:7641)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:4617)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:6999)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6978)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6945)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6924)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:8653)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7693)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/MessageQueue-JNI:   at
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d17b20)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.freelance.wwtlf.info, PID: 5937
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2413)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2373)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6945)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6924)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.rootViewRequestFocus(View.java:4746)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout(ViewGroup.java:4042)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViews(ViewGroup.java:3971)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.transition.Scene.enter(Scene.java:163)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.transition.TransitionManager.changeScene(TransitionManager.java:193)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.transition.TransitionManager.go(TransitionManager.java:342)
11-06 03:14:13.848 5937-5937/com.freelance.wwtlf.info E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.freelance.wwtlf.info.MainActivity$2.onFocusChange(MainActivity.java:71)
```

...

What object is pointing to `null`?

**Update**:
When I have changed `OnFocusChangeListener` to `onClickListener` everything worked fine. But I still don't understand why...

Comment: check for null for the calendar and seearchScene and you'll know if thats it :)

Comment: your line no 71 and 72 what is code on it.... it is causing exception

Comment: Line 71: TransitionManager.go(searchScene);

Comment: searchScene and calendarScene are not null
searchScene = {Scene@831697111936} 
 mContext = {MainActivity@831697049664} 
 mEnterAction = null
 mExitAction = null
 mLayout = null
 mSceneRoot = {FrameLayo....